# Firebase Functions for nested tables of Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql, google-cloud-functions

I have "issues" table in my database, each issue in this table has own id and "comments" table which contains comments on this issue.
I need a function which after adding comment will send a notification. But I don't know how to trigger it for "comments" table for each issue. I have the next function:

```
exports.sendComentNotitification = 
functions.database.ref('issues/{comments}').onWrite(event => {
console.log('Push notification event triggered');
const mydata = event.data.val()
console.log('Push notification event triggered',mydata, 'pushId', event.params.pushId);
console.log('Owner id',mydata.owner)
})
```

But this trigger works when any new data is added to the "issues" table.
Could you please give me an advice how I can implement what I described above? Thanks.

Comment: I have a feeling you're looking for `functions.database.ref('issues/{issueid}/comments/{commentid}')`. But note that this means you're nesting comments under each issue, which goes against Firebase's recommendation to keep your data structure flat and not nest different entity types.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks, but where I can get {issueid} and {commentid} values?

Comment: They're available under `event.params.issueid` and `event.params.commentid`. Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#specify_the_database_instance_and_path

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Many thanks, it works. Regarding: `But note that this means you're nesting comments under each issue, which goes against Firebase's recommendation to keep your data structure flat and not nest different entity types.` is it mean that I should have detached "comments" table which will contain issue id to fetch issue data and user id to fetch user FCM token?